# JavaScript function not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am making a tic-tac-toe game in which I have a series of 9 buttons. I change the background image to an `X` or an `O` based on the boolean value of variable `isX`.

I have a `div` with an id `stage` which holds all the buttons of class `square`. I added a listener on the `stage` and passed it an `event` parameter. However, the function `clickHandler` is not recognized.  Chrome says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined 2Players.html:38
(anonymous function)
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="stage">

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#stage{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.square{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
        const ROWS = 3;
        const COLS = 3;
        const GAP = 10;
        const SIZE = 64;
        var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");
        var lotOfButtons = [];

        var winningPatterns = ["123","159","147",
                               "258","357","369",
                               "456","789"];
        var isX = true;
        var player1Pattern = "";
        var player2Pattern = "";

        stage.addEventHandler("click",clickHandler,false);
        prepareBoard();

        function prepareBoard(){
            for(var row = 0;row<ROWS;row++){
            for(var col = 0;col < COLS;col++){
                var square = document.createElement("button");
                square.setAttribute("class","square");
                stage.appendChild(square);
                lotOfButtons.push(square);
                square.style.left = col * (SIZE+GAP) + "px";
                square.style.top = row * (SIZE+GAP) + "px";
            }
        }
        function clickHandler(event){
            if(isX===true){
                event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/X.PNG)";
                isX = false;
            }else{
                event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/O.PNG)";
                isX = true;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: aside your question, you might benefit from using a spritesheet and just offsetting the background position instead of swapping images.

Comment: @KaiQing Sure thing, will learn that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some syntax and semantic errors in the code -- possibly more than I caught, but it is in a working state.

1. You only closed one of the braces in the nested `for` loops in `prepareBoard`.  This leads to `clickHandler` being defined *inside* `prepareBoard` rather than on `window`.
2. It's `addEventListener`, not `addEventHandler`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pgQ8/